# What are the unused 240V breakers in my panel for?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, 240v

The main service panel in my house has eight 2 pole breakers in it.  It breaks down as:
2 40A breakers for the AC units
2 50A breakers for the furnaces
1 40A breaker for the stove
1 30A breaker for the dryer
2 30A breakers that are unlabeled, but have 10ga wire landed on both.

We have a gas water heater, so no need for 240V power there.

My question is this: Any idea what the two unlabeled breakers could be for?  I cannot think of any other 240V loads.  We do not have a subpanel anywhere, no hot tub, no RV plug, generator backfeed... I have them turned off now, but have not noticed a change in anything.  I would like to repurpose one of them to feed a subpanel in my shed, but don't want to drop something in the house.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Follow the wire. Given it's a typical water heater size, see if there's a junction box near the water heater location with capped off 10Ga wires in it, but other than that, follow the wire.

Comment: I followed it as far as I could-- which is to say, where it exited the main service.  I plan to get up in the attic (where the water heater is) and checking this evening.  Any suggestion on how to trace out the circuit?  I have a fox and hound for outlets, but that is not going to help me much if I don't know where the other end of the line is.

Comment: Do you have a separate oven or fancy built in microwave? Any special tools or EV charger in the garage or shop? If you don't notice anything amiss for several days with the breakers off I would feel pretty confident you are ok to repurpose them...

Comment: I don't think there's any way anyone who does _not_ have access to your house (either you or an electrician you hire) could _possibly_ answer this question. The _only_ way to know is to physically follow the wire. You could also look for anything that looks like it _used_ to be an outlet, but now has a blank face plate on it, because it may lead there.

Comment: Nothing fancy about the oven, other than it has two bays.  But it also has its own dedicated 240V breaker, and I successfully ran both ovens/bays with the breakers in question open.  I have a built in microwave, on its own dedicated 120V circuit.  No EV charger, minimal outlets in the garage, no shop-- yet.

Comment: If you are comfortable working in the panel, you can connect your Fox to the wires that connect to the breakers, and use your Hound to trace the wire.

Comment: I would look for A/C and hot tub feeds around perimeter of house too. Maybe wiring for an Instahot in the kitchen. Is it possible the house was fed by a well?

Comment: Turn them off and see what quits working.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson OP already tried that: "*I have them turned off now, but have not noticed a change in anything.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 x 50A for furnace *implies* electric heat. (If it was a heat pump, that would be combined with the 2 x 40A AC). That all points to "everything electric" because in most places if you have gas available then you use that for heat rather than electric. Plus "2x" indicates this is a large house. While you have a gas water heater now, my hunch is that your house originally had electric water heater(s) and, due to the size of the house, was wired up for **3** water heaters. That also fits with the (typical, but not universal) slower recovery time for residential electric water heaters compared to gas. One large gas water heater could easily produce as much hot water (between faster recovery and larger capacity) as 2 electric water heaters. Then at some point (my parents did this years ago, but they added gas heat at the same time), someone got gas piped into the house and replaced the electric water heaters with gas.

Comment: Great answer, thank you.  A little more information-- it is a larger two story house, AC and heat broken up between to units, one for upstairs and one for downstairs.  Yes, it is electric heat-- the only gas loads are the water heater and the fire place.  I will be in the attic tonight seeing if that is where there cables terminate.

Comment: Replacing electric appliances with gas is pretty common, when possible.  When our previous home was built (1989ish), there was a moratorium on new gas hook ups, so everything was electric.  Around 10 years after we moved in, the moratorium lifted.  The gas company would run the line into the neighborhood and up to your house for free, providing you connected one major appliance up to the gas, which most people jumped at.

Comment: Run the numbers for your local prices, but usually gas is SO MUCH CHEAPER than electric that replacing an electric furnace with gas is going to pay back VERY quickly.

Comment: @SteveSh Similar to my parents' house. Built in the early 1970s. "Oil crisis" == "No new oil or gas" == "all electric houses". Which was stupid govt. because the natural gas was from the US anyway, and that just increased electric demand - and peaker plants for electric are often natural gas. Stupid. But I digress. When gas company came around in the 90s, the deal was **2** appliances. So they did heat + water heater. Heat was the big draw for them - baseboard heat before which was never good enough on cold days.

Comment: I don't want to get political here, but unfortunately many cities (esp. in California) are banning natural gas for heating and cooking.  Now they want everything electric. CA has trouble keeping power supplied during heat waves for A/C and cuts power during hot, high wind events to minimize the chance of wildfire. What's going to happen to emissions when everybody fires up a generator during power outages. And what's powering the electric? peaker plants, nukes, coal, etc.   If this comment violates rules here at SE, I'm sorry, but it has to be said. Delete if admins see fit.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson Certain people want to: ban fossil fuels because of originally pollution and now global warming (both noble goals, but...) and then ban nukes because of Fukushima, etc. (again, real problems, but workable) and because of the other kind of nukes (and again, there are ways to keep one from connecting to the other) and nuclear waste (which can be managed, but NIMBY so it never does) so "all electric" but "not enough electric". Seems some people didn't learn in kindergarten that you can't have everything you want all the time, that you have to compromise. But I digress...

Comment: OP yeah, converting your  heat to gas will save you a fortune, *unless* you're in a location with unusual power rates.  Example: North Carolina has plenty of nuclear, so so they have an "electric heat" plan at <1 cent per KWH (really) plus (here's the gotcha) whatever your peak usage is for 30 minutes in the month, $7/kilowatt for that.  Works out to 2 cents a KWH for *continuous* usage like Bitcoin miners, and 3-4 cents for typical heating load. In fact on that plan, simply turning off one of those 50A breakers for a month would save you $70.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Nuclear is largely an issue of siting. Certain places are poor choices for nuclear plants (earthquake country; places water is scarce) and other places are a good choice because the neighbors don't complain and they are unlikely to do much environmental damage (Chornobyl Zone of Alienation, and all the support facilities are already there, even a town, Slavutich just outside the zone aka Pripyat 2.0).

Comment: @Harper Peak demand pricing is much more realistic but people complain because they don't understand it. Around here commercial has it but not residential